# users cant login without setting the remember me option in yii?

Tags: yii

The main problem is that the user cant login the site without the remember the option. I have modified login function to check the user access and redirect to their particular action but it doesn't work id the user don't choose the remember me option at the time of login.Here is my code of login action..

```
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        if($model->validate() && $model->login()){
            $user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;

            $record=Users::model()->findByPk($user_id);
            if($record->masrole->name == 'Admin'){

                $this->redirect(array('//users/admin'));}
            if($record->masrole->name == 'Merchant'){ $this->redirect(array('//users/Description','user'=>$record->username));
            }

        }
    }
```

and here is my config file.

```
'components'=>array(

            'user'=>array(
                'class' => 'WebUser',
                'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                'autoRenewCookie' => true,
                'identityCookie' => array('domain' => '.xxxxx.com'),
                'loginUrl'=>'http://xxxxx.com/login',
                ),
            'session' => array(
                    'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
                    'cookieParams' => array('domain' => '.xxxxxx.com'),
                    'timeout' => 3600,
                'connectionID' => 'db',
                    'sessionName' => 'session',
                 ),
```

And this is  my model login function

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {

        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->email,$this->password);

        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {

        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else{ 
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is WebUser.php

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {


private $_model;

 function isAdmin(){
   $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
   return intval($user->mas_role_id) == 1;

    }

   function isMerchant(){
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    return intval($user->mas_role_id) == 2;
    }

 }

// Load user model.
  protected function loadUser($id=null)
  {

  if($this->_model===null)
  {
      if($id!==null)
      $this->_model=Users::model()->findByPk($id);
  }
  return $this->_model;
  }
}
```

And Last this is User Identity

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{

private $_id;


public function authenticate()
{
    $ctiteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $ctiteria->condition = "email = '".$this->username."' OR username =     '".$this->username."'";
    $record=Users::model()->find($ctiteria);

    if($record===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if ($record->status != 1)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;

    else if($record->password !== md5($this->password))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->_id = $record->id;
        $this->setState('title', $record->email);
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;

}
public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
}
function isAdmin(){
$user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
return intval($user->mas_role_id) == 1;

}

 function isMerchant(){
  $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
  return intval($user->mas_role_id) == 2;
}
 protected function loadUser($id=null)
  {

  if($this->_model===null)
  {
      if($id!==null)
      $this->_model=Users::model()->findByPk($id);
  }
  return $this->_model;
    }
}
```

Comment: show code of WebUser.php and UserIdentity.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is important

```
if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
{

    $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
    Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
    return true;
}
```

make sure your execution enters this bloc... Try var_dump() to debug the error code

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#handling-authorization-result

Chapter 5

If the browser is redirected to the login page and the login is successful, we may want to redirect the browser back to the page that caused the authorization failure. How do we know the URL for that page? We can get this information from the returnUrl property of the user component. We can thus do the following to perform the redirection:

`Yii::app()->request->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);`

Comment: The var_dump($duration) gives out this warning. `session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent`

Comment: @SudhanshuSaxena And after that? Did the `$record->masrole->name` compare the name correctlly and redirect the user?? Yes the var_dump will generate output and error "already sent" but that's not the point, use `die;` to stop the script and debug

Comment: yes the $record->masrole->name is exactly same and the condition runs true.

Comment: So the line `$this->redirect(...)` doesn't work at all? Could it be a yii error or in your redirected controller/action you somehow destroy the session?

Comment: there is no error generated.The flow is that..The controller redirected to the `//users/Description` then it again redirect to the login form.I saw this flow in the chrome dataflow.But the normal view looks like we are not login and nothing happens.

Comment: Please post some more code of Users controller. Is `accessRules()` worked correctly? Did the action Description somehow reached but by the end it redirect back to login? Like through returnUrl

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28559/discussion-between-thanh-trung-and-sudhanshu-saxena)

Answer (score 0):

Just to reply if someone is having the same problem yet.
It could well be just that you have a space in your sessions name in config/main.php

Remove spaces in name and set 'cookieMode' => 'allow' or 'cookieMode' => 'only'.
Then clear your cookies and it should be working without remember me.